# Calculate SubTotal in Devexpress Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a simple `Devexpress` `Gridview`.

[image]

Here code;

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="MasterDataSource" Width="100%"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="CategoryID">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CategoryID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0" />
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CategoryName" VisibleIndex="1" />
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Description" VisibleIndex="2" />
        </Columns>
        <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="True" ExportMode="Expanded" />
        <Templates>
            <DetailRow>
                <dx:ASPxGridView ID="detailGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="DetailDataSource"
                    KeyFieldName="ProductID" Width="100%" OnBeforePerformDataSelect="detailGrid_BeforePerformDataSelect">
                    <SettingsDetail IsDetailGrid="true" ExportIndex="0" />
                    <Columns>
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0" />
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ProductName" VisibleIndex="1" />
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UnitPrice" VisibleIndex="2" />
                        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="QuantityPerUnit" VisibleIndex="3" />
                    </Columns>
                </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Is there any way calculate sub total of `Unit Price` column in Devexpress?

For this example; I just want total of `Unit Price` column (18 + 19 + 4.5 + 14 + 18 + 263.5 + 18 + 46 + 14 + 14 + 15 = `430`) in the bottom..

How can i do that?

**Best Regards,**

**Soner**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented using the ASPxGridView using the following approach:

1)  calculate summary in a separate method.
2)  use the detail GridView's DataBound and BeforeGetCallBackResult event handlers to set the label's text.  Here is my code:

```
protected int CalcPageSummary(ASPxGridView gridView, string fieldName) {
    GridViewDataColumn column = gridView.Columns[fieldName] as GridViewDataColumn;
    if(column == null)
        return 0;
    int pageIndex = gridView.PageIndex;
    int startRowIndex = pageIndex * gridView.SettingsPager.PageSize;
    int finishRowIndex = startRowIndex + gridView.SettingsPager.PageSize;
    if(finishRowIndex > gridView.VisibleRowCount)
        finishRowIndex = gridView.VisibleRowCount;
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = startRowIndex; i < finishRowIndex; i++) 
        result += Convert.ToInt32(gridView.GetRowValues(i, fieldName));
    return result;
}

private void SetColumnSummary(ASPxGridView gridView, string fieldName) {
    ASPxLabel lbl = gridView.FindFooterCellTemplateControl(gridView.Columns[fieldName], "ASPxLabel1") as ASPxLabel;
    if(lbl != null)
        lbl.Text = CalcPageSummary(gridView, fieldName).ToString();
}
protected void ASPxGridView2_BeforeGetCallbackResult(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SetColumnSummary((ASPxGridView)sender, "UnitPrice");
}
protected void ASPxGridView2_BeforePerformDataSelect(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Session["CategoryID"] = (sender as ASPxGridView).GetMasterRowKeyValue();
}
protected void ASPxGridView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SetColumnSummary((ASPxGridView)sender, "UnitPrice");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about devexpress but in regular gridview you can easily calculate totals and show them on footer.

```
 double GrdTotal = 0;
    protected void grdList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UnitPrice"));
        GrdTotal += price;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label lblTotalPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("UnitPrice");
            lblTotalPrice.Text = GrdTotal.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Özgür Thanks but i wondering how can i do that in ASPxGridview.. Should be different with the normal Gridview.